# SpringBoot Microservices

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

configuration from application.properties

I am trying to pull the configuration details from application.properties rather from Git repository. Since my existing code pull details from GitRepository, I have deleted the bootstrap.properties & and created application.properties in my microservice project and had my all configuration there.

application.properties file has following two lines,

```
spring.application.name=document-service

server.port=8085
```

Now the issue is, it's still referring the configuration from bootstrap.properties file and trying to fetch the configuration from cloud-config-server. Below are the console logs.

```
[2m2022-08-02 19:12:32.460[0;39m [32m INFO [,,,][0;39m [35m14108[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888

[2m2022-08-02 19:12:34.857[0;39m [32m INFO [,,,][0;39m [35m14108[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available

[2m2022-08-02 19:12:34.857[0;39m [33m WARN [,,,][0;39m [35m14108[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I have tried all possibilties, still am not able to resolve. could you please provide your thoughts on this.

Comment: Is this with your java IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse)?  Or running the code?

Comment: Spring Boot works with default- and auto-configuration. Probably your Maven or Gradle build config file contains dependencies to Spring Boot Starter libraries, which trigger this default behavior. So please share the build files or adapt your dependencies.

Comment: @granadaCoder It's STS 4

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try below:

1. mvn clean install, since it is weird that the app is still looking for config server on startup without bootstrap file
2. if you no longer need the app to be config client you can remove the dependency in pom.xml as well.
3. you can create a different profile for local application.properties. It always make sense to have it different in case you want to go back to config in git.